# about showing continuous slider value in UISlider

Tags: ios, uislider

Here's what I want to do with UI Slider ....

I have a bunch of files with times and I show them based on slider value. The problem is I want to show the slider value when the user is changing/moving the slider. In other words, the value should change (and be shown on the screen) as the user is moving the slider (and not afterwards).

Can anyone please give me any idea how to do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You can ask to get a method called when the slider's value changes. Then using that change, you should update the text of a label.

To listen for the value's change:

```
[mySlider addTarget:self action:@selector(mySliderChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Then to update the label:

```
NSString *labelString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Slider value is %d", mySlider.value];
[myLabel setText:labelString];
```

Comment: This is what I am doing now. The problem is: the action handler is called once you release the slider...and not while the slider is moving... :(  .. any help ?

Comment: Set mySlider.continuous = YES.

Answer (score 6):

[UISlider class docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
mySlider.continuous = YES;


@property(nonatomic, getter=isContinuous) BOOL continuous
```

from docs:

> Discussion
>
> If YES, the slider sends update events
>   continuously to the associated
>   target’s action method. If NO, the
>   slider only sends an action event when
>   the user releases the slider’s thumb
>   control to set the final value.