# How can I fix my mathematical operation in xcode to give me the correct answer?

Tags: xcode, math, operations

I am building an app that does a lot of math and calculations.  I have slider values that are displayed in labels and I have to use those values in a function to get a final value. I have these slider values(the numbers are what i have as user input to test the formula and see if it works):

```
Ageslider=20, weightslider=144, feetslider=5,inchesslider=9.03.
```

I have to first convert weight,feet,and inches into metric to plug into the overall formula, but the user does not need to see those values. to turn those to metric the formula is this:

```
weightslider/2.2,  feetslider*12*2.54,   inchesslider*2.54.
```

Now for the overall formula:

```
66.473+5.0033*((feetslider*12.2.54)+(inchesslider*2.54))+13.7516*(weightslider/2.2)-6.755*ageslider
```

or simplified this is what the original formula is supposed to be:

```
66.473+5.0033*(height in cm)+13.7516*(weight in kg)-6.755*age
```

When i type the formula

```
(66.473+5.0033*((feetslider*12.2.54)+(inchesslider*2.54))+13.7516*(weightslider/2.2)-6.755*ageslider)
```

and then run the program and use the test numbers in the program I cannot get the final value to equal what it should.  I have put the formula in excel and ran it through my calculator with the correct order of operations and get `1708.7373`.  When I run it in the program it comes up with `1747.7`.

I then tried putting (float) in front of the slider values in the formula and the program got this: `1718.67`.  Then i tried putting (double) in front of the slider values and the program got this: `1689.62`.  Here is the actual code copied out of xcode that I am using:

```
label.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f",66.473+(5.0033*((feetslider.value*12*2.54)+(inchesslider.value*2.54)))+(13.7516*(weightslider.value/2.2))-(6.755*ageslider.value)];
```

It is also coming up with the warning: Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast.
I do not know what that means.

Somebody please help me, I have been stuck on this for hours trying to change the formula around to get the correct answer and  get rid of the warning but I cannot get it for the life of me!!!

Thanks!

Update!! here is the exact code I have now, still not coming up with right answer.
When I run the program I still get the error "Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast."  It shows up on the line with the "if(malebutton = Yes).

-(IBAction)malebutton{
    if (malebutton = YES) {

```
    //Intermediate values
    float totalWeight;
    totalWeight = weightslider.value*.45454545;
    float heightFeetToCM;
    heightFeetToCM =feetslider.value*12*2.54;
    float heightInchesToCM;
    heightInchesToCM = inchesslider.value*2.54;
    float totalHeight; 
    totalHeight = heightFeetToCM + heightInchesToCM;

    //Final Component Values
    float calculatedHeight;
    calculatedHeight = 5.0033*totalHeight;
    float calculatedWeight;
    calculatedWeight = 13.7516*totalWeight;
    float calculatedAge;
    calculatedAge = 6.755*ageslider.value;

    //Total Value
    float finalValue;
    finalValue = 66.473 + calculatedHeight + calculatedWeight - calculatedAge;

    totalcaloriesburnedlabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f",finalValue];
```

UPDATE 2;

Here is how i have the sliders connected to their labels.  Formats are the same for all of them, except for how many decimals I have displayed on each.

`-(IBAction)changeLabelFeet {
    feetLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%.0f",feetSlider.value];
}`

Comment: This may be frowned upon from the programming standpoint, but have you tried taking ordering of operations into your own hands? e.g. instead of "(feetslider.value*12*2.54)+(inchesslider.value*2.54)" in your formula, make an intermediate variable of "totalHeight = (feetslider.value*12*2.54)+(inchesslider.value*2.54)" then plug totalHeight into the formula you have for label.text = ......

Comment: this is a typo? (feetslider*12.2.54) did you want (feetslider*12*2.54)?  . But @tarheel is right, break it up with intermediate values.

Comment: Warren Burton, yes it is a typo it should be (feetslider*12*2.54).  @tarheel this might be a stupid question, but I am very new to all of this.  Where would I make the intermediate variable at/how would i code that?  Could you give me an example code?

Comment: I will have to look at it again when I am back at my own computer where I can see what Xcode says for myself (tomorrow or Monday). Since you said that you're new to all this, I thought I'd mention that you should start using the standard upper/lowercase convention  e.g. The way you are naming items now is feetslider, but it should be feetSlider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update from original answer:  I went back and tried it on Xcode myself.  I started with just writing the values (float age = 20;) in to see if the problem was in the calculation, and ended up getting the right answer, being 1708.74 (with the .2f setting on the float in the string).  I then decided to see if getting the values from the sliders were the issue, starting with just the age on a slider and everything else still hard coded, I got the wrong answer initially and quickly realized I didn't hook up my slider in IB.  After correcting that I got the right answer. Here is my code.

.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
IBOutlet UISlider *ageSlider;
IBOutlet UISlider *weightSlider;
IBOutlet UISlider *feetSlider;
IBOutlet UISlider *inchesSlider;


}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider *ageSlider;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider *weightSlider;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider *feetSlider;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider *inchesSlider;

@end
```

.m

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize myLabel;
@synthesize ageSlider;
@synthesize weightSlider;
@synthesize feetSlider;
@synthesize inchesSlider;

-(void)calculateLabel{

//float age = 20;
float age = ageSlider.value;
NSLog(@"My age slider value is %.2f", ageSlider.value);
//float weight = 144;
float weight = weightSlider.value;
NSLog(@"My weight slider value is %.2f", weightSlider.value);
//float heightFeet = 5;
float heightFeet = feetSlider.value;
NSLog(@"My feet slider value is %.2f", feetSlider.value);
//float heightInches = 9.03;
float heightInches = inchesSlider.value;
NSLog(@"My inches slider value is %.2f", inchesSlider.value);


float weightKG = weight*.454545;
float heightFeetToCM = heightFeet * 12 * 2.54;
float heightInchesToCM = heightInches * 2.54;
float totalHeight = heightFeetToCM + heightInchesToCM;

float calculatedHeight = 5.0033 * totalHeight;
float calculatedWeight = 13.7516 * weightKG;
float calculatedAge = 6.755 * age;

float finalValue = 66.473 + calculatedHeight + calculatedWeight - calculatedAge;

myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", finalValue];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    [self calculateLabel];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

So first, check to make sure your NSLog looks like this.....

2012-06-17 23:57:53.557 Testing6[1404:10103] My age slider value is 20.00

2012-06-17 23:57:53.559 Testing6[1404:10103] My weight slider value is 144.00

2012-06-17 23:57:53.559 Testing6[1404:10103] My feet slider value is 5.00

2012-06-17 23:57:53.559 Testing6[1404:10103] My inches slider value is 9.03

If it doesn't work after that, the only other thing I can think of is that it would be the fact that your sliders are probably not updating continuously (aka the label showing your slider value is showing 20 on age to the user, but its really set to 19). Which I might be able to help you with that if I dig through my old Xcode projects. Let me know.

Comment: No, it is still not coming up with the correct answer.  I will post the exact code I have in the next 2 comments as it is too long to post into one.

Comment: Sorry, realized I could edit the first question I asked.  I posted the code there so it is easier to read!

Comment: I used your example and coded the equivalents into my project. So now I have a new problem. I tested the program with what i thought were the numbers 20, 144, 5, and 9.03(those are the numbers that showed up in the labels). However, the NSLog printed out the numbers 20.17, 144.03, 4.74 and 9.03. So how do I get the slider values to actually equal what they are showing? Does that question make sense?  Also I have updated original question to show how i have the slider connected to the label.

Comment: Based on the fact that you have .0f set as what you show the user in your label, I assume you want to use integers in your calculations....then just use a floor or ceil function around the slider.value.  such as `float age = floor(ageSlider.value);`

Comment: I thought of that, however, several times(i will use the age slider for example)the value in the label will show 20, but then the NSLog will print out 19.67 or some other value close to 20.  Then other times the value will show 20 in the label, but NSLog prints out 20.23 or another decimal.  So if I use the floor function, and the slider value is really 19.67, then their age in the calculation would be 19, and not 20.  So i need a way to modify the slider values to actually equal what they say in the label.

Comment: Just do the same to the `feetLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%.0f",feetSlider.value];` line, make it `floor(feetSlider.value)`

Comment: Hate to be 'that guy' but if this solves your problem, dont forget to hit the check mark on the answer.

Comment: I would be happy to hit check mark on the answer because you have been so helpful, but that doesn't work either.  Here is the code. the label is still displaying a whole number, but the NSLog prints out a decimal with the number...
-(IBAction)changeLabelFeet {
 feetLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%.0f",floor(feetSlider.value)];

Comment: If your age is set to 20.23 and you use the `floor(feetSlider.value)`, what does the NSLog say it is?

Comment: Thats not how its working, the age only display wholenumbers & I want it to not only display a whole number, but I want it to actually only be whole numbers. i see 20 in the label display, but the NSLog is printing out 20.49 or another decimal. Here is the code I have for the two  "actions" that deal with age. 

-(IBAction)changeLabelAge {
 ageLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%.0f",floor(ageSlider.value)];

-(IBAction)maleButtonTapped{
 float age;
 age = (ageSlider.value);
 NSLog(@"My age value is %.2f",(ageSlider.value));
maleButtonTapped calculates the final value i need.

Comment: Notice you are using the floor function to round the value that goes into your ageLabel, but you are not using the floor function on the value that goes into your NSLog. Once you use the floor function it will come out as 20.00 (due to the .2f used in the string format. And you don't use the floor function in the actual value set as age, should be age = floor(ageSlider.value); use the floor function consistently and your problem will go away.

Comment: Glad to hear it. From your (IBAction)changeLabelAge: method it sounds like you are depending on the user to tell your app to update the UISlider values. If that is the case, try this to have your app do it for the user instead.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241310/about-showing-continuous-slider-value-in-uislider)